# Update package.json in several places after "npm i"

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

I want to be able to detect any new package installed according to my package.json file, so when ever I do "npm i", it will automatically added to another section on my package.json file.
For example, if I do "npm i axios", It will update in 2 places on my package.json file:
on "dependencies" as usual, and on new section I created: "extDependencies".
Is there any way to detect any new installed packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: [npm-scripts documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)

> If you want to run a specific script at a specific lifecycle event for
>   ALL packages, then you can use a hook script.
>
> Place an executable file at node_modules/.hooks/{eventname}, and it’ll
>   get run for all packages when they are going through that point in the
>   package lifecycle for any packages installed in that root.
>
> Hook scripts are run exactly the same way as package.json scripts.
>   That is, they are in a separate child process, with the env described
>   above.

You could use this to create a `postinstall` script (bash, python, node.js, etc) that reads the `npm_package_name` and `npm_package_version` environment variables and then use those to update the package.json.

Comment: I don't think that postinstall would not do any effect here, it's used to run when something is installed not if something is added as dependency to the problem, even if it's also installing. so it will run with `npm install` but not when using `npm install something`. postinstall would be needed in every package on npm for this to work correctly.

Comment: Thats true if you define it as a postinstall script within the package.json itself. But if you create it as a script within the node_modules/.hooks folder, then it is executed on every package install.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the hook part. Good to know you can do this.